# ASP/Net crystal report parameter prompt pops up. I'd like it Inline

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have an asp.net web application with a crystal reportviewer on a page. When the page loads the report it pops up the parameter prompt in a separate window and the actual report viewer is grayed out. The problem is that after the report renders, if they want to enter different parametersthe users can't click the back button on the browser and return to the parameter screen since it appears in a popup window and disappears after the enter their parameters. They have to click the link on the page that opens the report and re-open it to try again with new parameters.

What setting am I missing? How do I get the parameter prompt to display inline?

Comment: Why don't you input parameters on your page? and let the user click some button to show report. That button would pass parameters to report.

Comment: Because I want it (specifically the users want it) displayed inline via the report.